Flutter Firebase notification is not redirecting to relevant screen
I have a flutter app and the I use Firebase and flutter_local_notifications.
Currently, my app receives notifications and when I click them, it opens up the app. However it is not redirecting to the intended screen.
I have abstracted the code to have a bit of clarity and might be the issue. There is something that I might be missing. Here is my code:
firebase_notification.helper.dart
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as timezone;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as timezone;

class FirebaseNotificationHelper {
  static final _notification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void init() {
    _notification.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
      ),
    );
  }

  static pushNotification(
    RemoteMessage message,
  ) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      channelDescription: 'channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await _notification.show(1, message.notification?.title,
        message.notification?.body, platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
}

firebase.helper.dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/helpers/firebase_notification.helper.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/helpers/firestore.helper.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/helpers/page.helper.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/helpers/popup.helper.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/helpers/storage.helper.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/models/logged.user.model.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/modules/home/home.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/modules/preview_home/preview_home.dart';
import 'package:grocstock/services/house.service.dart';

initializeFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseNotificationHelper.init();
  listenToMessages(context);
}

initFirebaseMessaging() async {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  try {
    String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    storage.write(key: 'fcmToken', value: token);
    await initFireBaseHouseUser(token);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to get FCM token: $e');
  }

  await messaging.requestPermission();
}

listenToMessages(BuildContext context) {
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.data}');
    }
    bool notificationsEnabled = await checkAppPopUpPermission();
    bool actionNotificationsEnabled = await checkActionAppPopUpPermission();
    bool messageNotificationsEnabled = await checkMessageAppPopUpPermission();

    if (!notificationsEnabled) return;

    String type = message.data['type'];
    bool showNotification = true;

    if (type == 'ACTION' && !actionNotificationsEnabled) {
      showNotification = false;
    } else if (type == 'MESSAGE' && !messageNotificationsEnabled) {
      showNotification = false;
    }

    if (showNotification) {
      await FirebaseNotificationHelper.pushNotification(message);
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    await _redirectToHouse(context, message);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message != null) {
      print(
          'App opened from terminated state by notification with data: ${message.data}');
      _redirectToHouse(context, message);
    }
  });
}

Future<void> _redirectToHouse(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
  try {
    String? houseId = message.data['houseId'];
    if(houseId != null && houseId.isNotEmpty) {
      var house = await getHouse(context, houseId);
      var user = await safeReadFromStorage('user', null);
      var loggedUser = LoggedUser.fromJson(jsonDecode(user!));

      String isAdmin = message.data['isAdmin'];
      if(isAdmin == 'true') {
        print('Navigate to Saved house');
        redirectToPage(context, PreviewHomePage(house: house, user: loggedUser));
      } else {
        redirectToPage(context, HomePage(house: house, user: loggedUser));
        print('Navigate to actual house');
      }
      //
      // SplashScreenState.navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
      //   housePageSelection(
      //     message.data['houseId'],
      //     loggedUser,
      //   ),
      // );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}


splash.page.dart
class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'Main Navigator');
  DarkThemeProvider themeChangeProvider = DarkThemeProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeFirebase();
  }
  _initializeFirebase() async {
    await initializeFirebase(context);
  }


  Future<bool> _checkTermsAccepted() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool('termsAccepted') ?? false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) {
        return themeChangeProvider;
      },
      child: Consumer<DarkThemeProvider>(
        builder: (BuildContext builderContext, DarkThemeProvider value,
            Widget? child) {
          return FutureBuilder<bool>(
            future: _checkTermsAccepted(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                bool termsAccepted = snapshot.data ?? false;
                return MaterialApp(
                  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                  title: 'Welcome',
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  theme: Styles.themeData(
                      themeChangeProvider.darkTheme, builderContext),
                  home: termsAccepted
                      ? Login(shouldRedirect: true)
                      : const TermsAndConditionsPage(),
                  onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
                  builder: BotToastInit(),
                  navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
                );
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried passing BuildContext down as well as use GlobalKey<NavigatorState>.
There are three scenarios that I need to fix and right now the app behaves weirdly.

When the app is closed.
When the app is minimised.
When the app is open.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.1+2
  firebase_core: ^3.4.0
  cloud_firestore: ^5.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.0


To properly handle Firebase notification navigation in Flutter when the app is in different state i recommend centralizing your navigation logic and using a more structured approach like this
class NotificationService {
static final _instance = NotificationService._();
static NotificationService get instance => _instance;
NotificationService._();

Future<void> setupNotifications(BuildContext context) async {
// Handle notification when app is in terminated state
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleNotification);

// Handle notification when app is in background
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleNotification);

// Handle notification when app is in foreground
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
  // Show local notification
  showLocalNotification(message);
 });
}

void handleNotification(RemoteMessage? message) {
if (message == null) return;

final houseId = message.data['houseId'];
final isAdmin = message.data['isAdmin'] == 'true';

if (houseId != null && houseId.isNotEmpty) {
  navigateToHouse(houseId, isAdmin);
   }
  }
}

Use it in your splash screen like this
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  NotificationService.instance.setupNotifications(context);
 }


When I pass the context down this is the error that I am getting: Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. E/flutter (15061): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

use global navigator key instead of BuildContext in your app just create a global key with navigator state  use it  in your notification handler  and in your material app and get the current state
just use the navigator key instead of context for navigation.
